# Observerable does not invoke view change event IsAuthenticated$ | async

Tags: angular, observable

I've read about change detection strategies. I see that I need invoke the change event manually on a subscribe event. But I thought that the | async pipe is designed for, does not it? It does not work in my case.

Comment: Can You be more specific to paste your code at least?

Comment: I see that service where I get the observable is created twice so I have two different observables. But why is not the service singleton?

Answer (score 1):

No, `async` pipe doesn't trigger changed detection. No pipe triggers change detection. A pipe has a method `transform` that is executed during change detection which is supposed to return a current value. This method is triggered inside `updateRenderer` function that is executed by change detection mechanism.

You can read more about `updateRenderer` in the [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d#163d).

Comment: I thought so but, the problem is in another issue.

Comment: I thought your question is about whether pipes trigger change detection